# Обучение автомобиля следовать маршруту GPS

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Всех приветствую.

Я пытаюсь сделать свой первый автопилот.

Мой первый проект был достаточно примитивен:

Машина просто следовала по дороге, держа линию.

В том проекте я использовал модель нейронной сети Nvidia.

Все работало отлично, машина точно следовала линиям.

Но у меня появился вопрос:

Как заставить машину следовать определенному маршруту?

В качестве GPS я думаю использовать GTA 5 маршрут:

[image: gta 5 hud]

А само изображение с "камеры" обрезать до такого состояния:

[image: full]

Но! Отсюда ещё 1 вопрос:

Как заставить машину следовать и линии на дороге и маршруту GPS?

Я пробовал такой способ:

Ставил маркер на карте, прокладывался маршрут. Как входное изображение использовал как раз что-то типа такого:

[image: full]

И в качестве "пометок" были клавиши A, W, S, D.

(преобразовывал в [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0] и т.д)

Но машина либо вовсе съезжала с маршрута и ехала непонятно куда, либо следовала исключительно линии на дороге, совершенно игнорируя маршрут GPS.

Прошу помощи, хотя бы направление в ту сторону, куда мне нужно копать.

Comment: Глупо, но может создать невидимую глазу дорогу на которую будет ориентироваться машина